# my WillPopScope doent work and it does not reach my if else

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a webview and I want to press go back phone button without closing the app. I have onWillPop but it only prints "onWillPop: Checking if WebView can go back..." and not reaching my if else.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebViewScreen> createState() => _WebViewScreenState();
}

class _WebViewScreenState extends State<WebViewScreen> {
  late WebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        print("onWillPop: Checking if WebView can go back...");
        if (await _webViewController.canGoBack()) {
          print("onWillPop: WebView can go back, going back.");
          _webViewController.goBack();
          return false; 
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://aptibapa.site",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
            _webViewController = controller;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me which version of webview_flutter and flutter version you are using.

Comment: I have version 3.0.4, I tried using the latest version and I encountered an error that I'm not familiar with

Answer (score 0):

> you shoud always return "false" in willPop function. before it you shoud check yor if statement and do proper action. Going back or else ...

```
  onWillPop: () async {
   if(await _webViewController.canGoBack()){
    // going back in web view
    _webViewController.goBack();
   } else {
    // going back in app or close app
    exit(0);
   }
   return false;
  }
```